# In checkout function g_tot calculation brings garbage value

Tags: c

In this code at checkout function `g_tot` calculation brings garbage value. I think its because I'm calculating two variables from another two functions, but I don't know how to fix it.  There's another error in restaurant function in if condition if I  enter value more than 8 it'll bring garbage value to tot. But the most important one is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

// Global variables

int room,answr,days=0;
char name[20],choose;
int i=0,tot=0,p_tot=0,g_tot=0,z=0;
int p_price[2][5]={4000,10000,20000};


void screenheader()
{
printf("\n                    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");
printf("\n                    ::                                  ::");
printf("\n                    ::   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   ::");
printf("\n                    ::   @                          @   ::");
printf("\n                    ::   @         WELCOME          @   ::");
printf("\n                    ::   @           TO             @   ::");
printf("\n                    ::   @       SURF  HOTEL        @   ::");
printf("\n                    ::   @                          @   ::");
printf("\n                    ::   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   ::");
printf("\n                    ::                                  ::");
printf("\n                    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");

}

void check_in()
{


int contact_No[20],NIC[10];
char first_name[10],last_name[10],Country[10];


system("cls");
screenheader();
printf("\n1. Packages");
printf("\n2. Room Allocation");
printf("\n3. Back\n\n");


scanf(" %d",&answr);
switch(answr)
{
case 1:{
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\n\nPer 2 Persons");
        printf("\n\t\tPackage Name   >>>> Couple");
        printf("\n\t\tRs.4000/=  per day");
        printf("\n\t\tBed  >>>> 1");
        printf("\n\t\t *Tv Available");

        printf("\n\n\n\n\t\t\nPer 4 Persons\n\t\tPackage Name   >>>> 
       Family");
        printf("\n\t\tRs.10,000/=  per day");
        printf("\n\t\tBed  >>>> 2");
        printf("\n\t\t*Tv Available \n\t\t*A/C \n\t\t*WIFI");

        printf("\n\n\n\nPer 8 Persons\n\t\tPackage Name   >>>> Deluxe");
        printf("\n\t\tRs.20,000/=  per day");
        printf("\n\t\tBed  >>>> 3 Large ");
        printf("\n\t\t *Tv Available \n\t\t*A/C \n\t\t*WIFI\n\t\t*Local 
        Travel Guide\n\t\t*Balcony with a view\n\t\t*Writing desk");
        printf("\n\n*Press 1 to go back");
       getch();
       check_in();


        break;
        }
case 2:{

        printf("What package do you want?");
        scanf(" %d",&i);
        p_tot=p_tot+p_price[i-1];

            if(i == 1)
            {
                printf("You have selected Couple package");
            }
            else if (i == 2)
            {
                printf("You have selected Family Package ");
            }
            else if (i == 3)
            {
                printf("You have selected Deluxe package");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n\nWrong input, please refer to packages and try 
           again.\nPress Enter to select another package");

                getch();
                check_in();
            }


        printf("\nEnter First Name:\n");
        scanf(" %s",&first_name);
        printf("Last Name:\n");
        scanf(" %s",&last_name);
        printf("How many days do you want to stay?");
        scanf(" %d",&days);
        printf("Enter your Country:");
        scanf(" %s",&Country);
        printf("Enter your NIC No:");
        scanf(" %d",&NIC);
        printf("Enter your Contact No:");
        scanf(" %d",&contact_No);

        printf("Hello %s %s you have booked a Room for 
%d",&first_name,&last_name,days);
        getch();
        system("cls");
        int main();
        }

        case 3: main();
}


}

void restaurant()
{
int fc[6];
char ans;
char food[8][30]={"Bread","Noodles","Salad","Popcorn","Chocolate ice 
cream","Vanilla ice cream","Cold Coffee","Milk Shake"};
int price[8]={180,120,65,55,70,70,110,200};

printf("Press Enter To Continue To The Restaurant  ");
getchar();
system("cls");

printf("\n\n\n\n\n\t                       *********");
printf("\n\t                       MENU CARD");
printf("\n\t                       *********\n\n\n");
printf("\n              Food Code\t\tprice\t\t Food Name\n");

for(i=0;i<8;i++)
{
printf("\n\t\t%d",i+1);
 printf("\t\tRs. %d",price[i]);
printf("\t\t%s",food[i]);
}
printf("\n\n\n\t *PRESS 0 TO GO TO THE MAIN MENU\n\t *PRESS 1 TO ORDER FOOD  
: ");
scanf(" %d",&answr);
switch(answr)
{
case 0:
    {
        main();
        break;
    }
case 1:do
{
    printf("\n\nENTER THE FOOD CODE YOU WANT TO HAVE :: ");
    scanf("%d", &z);

if (z < 1 || z > 8)
    {
       printf("Invalid food code\n");

    }

        tot=tot+price[z-1];
        printf("total so far is Rs.%d\n",tot);
        printf("DO YOU WANT MORE(Y/N) ::");
        scanf(" %c", &ans);



} while(ans=='y'|| ans=='Y');
  printf("\n\nYour bill is Rs.%d",tot);
  printf("\nYour bill will be added to the total bill at checkout");
  printf("\n\nPress Enter to go back to main menu");
  getch();
  system("cls");
  main();

}
}


void check_out()
{
system("cls");
screenheader();
printf("\n\nAre you sure you want checkout (Y/N)");
scanf(" %c",&choose);

if(choose=='n' || choose=='N')

{
    main();
}
else if(choose== 'Y' || choose=='y')
{
    system("cls");
    screenheader();
    g_tot=p_tot+tot;
    printf("Total");
    printf("%d",g_tot);

}

}

int main()
{


screenheader();
printf("\n\n\nPress Enter To Continue");
getchar();
system("cls");
screenheader();
printf("\n\n\n\n\t\t        *************   \n");
printf("\t\t        * MAIN MENU *   \n");
printf("\t\t        *************   \n\n\n");
printf("\t\t\t01. Check In \n");
printf("\t\t\t02.Restaurant\n");
printf("\t\t\t03.Checkout \n");
printf("\n\t\t\t04.Exit");

scanf(" %d",&answr);
switch(answr)
{
case 1:{
    check_in();
break; }

case 2:{
    restaurant();
break; }

case 3: {
        check_out();
        }

}


return 0;

 }
```

Comment: Please try to reduce the volume of code here. Also describe the error you are seeing - what garbage comes out, and what did you expect. A quick look suggests nothing wrong in that function, so you probably had an earlier error? Also, `int p_price[2][5]={4000,10000,20000};` only initialises three out of the 10 fields; that should be fixed as it could be the source of your error.

Comment: This is the whole code. I'm sorry I couldn't reduce it because I had no Idea where the problem could be

Comment: Also, `p_tot=p_tot+p_price[i-1];` - do not ignore compiler warnings! This could very well be the source of your error.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to programming I though `[2]` means number of elements in array and `[5]` for maximum number of number in one element. Could you tell me how to fix it

Comment: @KenY-N there a error saying assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast. I searched but couldnt fix it

Comment: @Joeell Creating an [mcve] will be helpful both to those answering your question and to you, in the sense that narrowing down the problem to one particular area of the code can often help you suss out the bug.

Comment: @Ken Y-N Detail: `int p_price[2][5]={4000,10000,20000}` initializes all 10 elements, 3 as specified and the rest to 0.  Still the 0 zeros may not meet OP's gaol.

Comment: @Joeell Your need to post the input used, else the post in unclear.

Comment: @Joeell Save time.  I get 15 warnings.  Enable all your warnings too and handle those issues.

Comment: @KenY-N  As you said  `int p_price[2][5]={4000,10000,20000}` was the error. It fixes the g_tot issue, but still stcuked in if repetition error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if condition if I enter value more than 8 it'll bring garbage value to tot.

This is as expected.  When `z > 8`, code attempts to access outside `price[]` range.  Result: *undefined behavior* (UB).  The prior `if (z < 1 || z > 8)` did not steer code away from `price[z - 1]`.  Rest of code including `g_tot = p_tot + tot;` is now questionable.

```
int price[8] = {180, 120, 65, 55, 70, 70, 110, 200};
...
if (z < 1 || z > 8) {
  printf("Invalid food code\n");
}

tot = tot + price[z - 1];  // UB here
...
g_tot = p_tot + tot;
```

Do not access `price[z - 1]` unless `z` in the range [1...8].

---

Other problems exist:  Best to enable all compilers warnings and seem them (12+) yourself.

Comment: I'm a noob to coding could you please explain what should I do?

Comment: @Joeell When `z` is not in the valid range,code could 1) not proceed to `tot = tot + price[z - 1];` and 2) ask for input again.

Comment: Yes thats the issue. Fixed it by adding a `else` for  `tot = tot + price[z - 1];`